# setting different hbase timeouts in happybase

Tags: hbase, happybase

I looked into the code of HappyBase Connection class and also the documentation here: http://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user.html#establishing-a-connection

but I was not able to find any way to set different Hbase timeouts like hbase.rpc.timeout, hbase.rpc.shortoperation.timeout in happybase.

How can I set these params?

Answer (score -1):

You can set the timeout using the `timeout` parameter, it was recently introduced in happybase.

Check the implementation [here](https://github.com/wbolster/happybase/blob/master/happybase/connection.py#L104).